# How can I translate 中國傳統社會屬父系社會，以男性繼承世系血脈 into English?

Tags: translation

The sentence is 「中國傳統社會屬父系社會，以男性繼承世系血脈」. Should it be translated into the sentence "the traditional Chinese society is patrilineal and adopts a male lineage system"?

Answer (score 2):

中國傳統社會屬父系社會，
Chinese society, traditionally, was/is a patrimonial society,

以男性繼承世系血脈。
where the bloodline is passed down through the men.

Has anything changed?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.